# Why update() is removing the previous data of child in firebase when sending multiple objects?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My firebase structure has a child named "playerNames". When I send the data like this:

```
firebase.database().ref("games/" + gameId + "/playerNames/").update({[playerName]: 1});
```

The player name gets appended along with the value 1.

[image: Structure]

But when I send the data like this:

```
var player = {authId: uid, joinTime: firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP, leaveTime: "", name: playerName, status: "1", ticket1: "", ticket2: "", ticket3: "", totalTickets: totalTickets};

var data = {};
data["games/" + gameId + "/players/" + playerId] = player;
data["games/" + gameId + "/playerNames"] = {[playerName]: 1};

firebase.database().ref().update(data);
```

The previous data in the **playerNames** gets overwrited.

[image: Structure]

Why is it so. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because,

In the first case you pass the `{[playerName]: 1}` Object to the [`update()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#update) method and the update is applied to the `"games/" + gameId + "/playerNames/"` node

while,

In the second case, you pass the entire `data` Object and the update is applied to the root node of the database (so the entire `"games/" + gameId + "/playerNames/"` node is replaced).

You need to do as follows:

```
var player = {authId: uid, joinTime: firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP, leaveTime: "", name: playerName, status: "1", ticket1: "", ticket2: "", ticket3: "", totalTickets: totalTickets};

var data = {};
data["games/" + gameId + "/players/" + playerId] = player;
data["games/" + gameId + "/playerNames/" + playerName] = 1;

firebase.database().ref().update(data);
```

It will let "untouched" all the other nodes under `"games/" + gameId + "/playerNames/"`.

Comment: The world need geniuses like you. Thank you gentleman, this worked like a charm.